# Date convolution thru timestamped transition table -- how to

Tags: google-bigquery

We need to convolute every day from a point in the past up to now against a list of timestamped, boolean device transitions. The final output should be a table that has a date:device_id entry for every day it is online (otherwise no entry for that date).

Here is an example transition table for a single device:

[image: Device Transition Table]

To generate the convolution calendar:

```
  calendar AS (
    SELECT day
    FROM UNNEST (GENERATE_DATE_ARRAY('2011-05-15', CURRENT_DATE())) AS day
  ),
```

Then, to generate at least a table that only has the transition dates AFTER the transition event, so they can then subsequently be ranked and the most recent chosen (CROSS JOIN here -- yuck!):

```
joined_with_cal AS (

SELECT 
  cal.day as online_date,
  otr.when_changed,
  otr.device_id,
  otr.is_online,
  otr.rank_by_date
FROM 
  calendar AS cal
CROSS JOIN 
  ordered_transitions otr
WHERE
  cal.day >= DATE(otr.when_changed)
),
```

Then, the code that attempts to rank and choose the most recent record in the partition by timestamp (when_changed or ranked_by_date -- neither seems to work):

```
SELECT  
  online_date,
  when_changed,
  device_id,
  is_online,
  rank_by_date,
FROM (
  SELECT
    online_date,
    when_changed,
    device_id,
    is_online,
    rank_by_date,
    RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY device_id ORDER BY rank_by_date ASC) as final_rank
  FROM
    joined_with_cal
)
WHERE
  final_rank = 1 AND
  --  online_date < '2017-08-01' AND
  device_id = 419609
ORDER BY
  online_date,
  when_changed,
  device_id
```

However, this doesn't work and is obviously ugly.

Can someone suggest a correct, elegant solution?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: agree. it is ugly and as you say - does not work! to suggest you something  - you need to explain what exactly your logic is! Also if you show expected result based on sample data on top of your question  - would be helpful. P.S. i tried to derive the logic from code you referenced  - and what i see makes no much sense to me so far

Answer (score 1):

@Mikhail: thanks for looking at it and sorry my explanation was not clearer.

After a discussion with a colleague, I ended up using a self-join which seems to work:

```
trans_as_range_not_first AS (

  SELECT
    t1.device_id,
    t1.rank_by_when,
    t2.when_changed as online_start,
    t1.when_changed as online_stop,
    t1.account_id,
    t1.account_name,
    t1.server_type
  FROM
    ordered_trans AS t1  -- lower in rank index, later in time
  LEFT JOIN
    ordered_trans AS t2  -- greater in rank index, earlier in time
  ON
    t1.device_id = t2.device_id AND 
    t1.rank_by_when+1 = t2.rank_by_when  -- current and next row
  WHERE
    t1.is_online = 0 AND t2.is_online = 1
  GROUP BY
    device_id,
    rank_by_when,
    online_start,
    online_stop,
    account_id,
    account_name,
    server_type
),
```

Comment: And just to be clear and complete, I did not need to do the complete convolution since records of time ranges are easily selectable in a JOIN to get the number of unique devices over and arbitrary date range.